# In Godot, how do I reposition the center of my mesh?

Tags: rotation, godot, mesh, godot-4

When importing a Unity package to Godot via Unidot importer, I noticed that a few imported models have their child rotations and transformations off-center from their expected points.

For example, here is a model of a toilet seat. In Unity, if I adjust the `x` rotation of the lid, it rotates at the hinge to appear closed.

[image: Toilet model]

But in Godot, it rotates like this:

[image: Godot rotation]

How do I resolve this? Apologizes if this is obvious, I am not experienced in 3D modeling.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. When it imported the model, it added some values in its transform (which I reverted in the picture), I just needed to add the inverse of that transform in the mesh renderer.

Comment: Can you explain/show the steps you took yo do that, to help future users struggling with similar problems?